# Shape Detection in opencv Java

Tags: java, android, opencv, shapes, detection

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

  // get the camera frame as gray scale image
    Mat gray = null;

    if (DETECT_RED_OBJECTS_ONLY) {
        gray = inputFrame.rgba();
    } else {
        gray = inputFrame.gray();
    }


    // the image to output on the screen in the end
    // -> get the unchanged color image
    Mat dst = inputFrame.rgba();
```

Here code is used

> org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame; But i want to do something like this.I want to convert this android code to `opencv` `java`

```
public static Mat onCameraFrame(Mat inputFrame) {

    Mat gray = null;
if (DETECT_RED_OBJECTS_ONLY) {
    gray = inputFrame.rgba();
} else {
    gray = inputFrame.gray();
}


// the image to output on the screen in the end
// -> get the unchanged color image
Mat dst = inputFrame.rgba();
```

now there is no such a thing `rgba()`  & `gray()` .Please anyone help me to solve this

Comment: Initially  private static final boolean DETECT_RED_OBJECTS_ONLY = true;

Comment: I don't understand your question, if you change your Object it's actually obvious that the methods will not be the same. What do you exactly want to do ? 
Convert to gray the image ?